# What is the COMM_TYPE in the simple message protocol?

Tags: ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When using the simple message protocol, messages that are sent contain a COMM_TYPE located in the header. According to the [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/simple_message?distro=indigo#Message_Structure), this is an integer that identifies the communications type.

I can't really find any other information on this value. Between what types of communications does it choose? Does it choose between TCP and UDP? And what values can it have? Something like 0 for TCP and 1 for UDP?

Thx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207067/what-is-the-comm_type-in-the-simple-message-protocol?/) by [Gengoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/22122/gengoz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2015-04-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry I missed this one.

The values for `comm_type` are actually documented in the `simple_message.h` file in the `simple_message` package of the `industrial_core` stack (from [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/industrial_core/blob/526f5dc434cf4a4184916277615a169225dc9ec6/simple_message/include/simple_message/simple_message.h#L93-L102))
:

```
enum CommType
{
  INVALID = 0,
  TOPIC = 1,
  SERVICE_REQUEST = 2,
  SERVICE_REPLY = 3
};
```

You can also find the defined values for the other parts of the header there.

Additionally, the `simple_message` package has been documented using Doxygen, which is automatically generated by the ROS buildfarm. You can access that documentation [here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/simple_message/html/), which is also accessible from the [simple_message wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/simple_message) (top-right, *Package Links*, *Code API*). You'll want to open the page for the [SimpleMessage](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/simple_message/html/classindustrial_1_1simple__message_1_1SimpleMessage.html) class, which contains references to the [StandardMsgTypes](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/simple_message/html/namespaceindustrial_1_1simple__message_1_1StandardMsgTypes.html#a0f513324d43078fb9869c4d17bdad567), [CommTypes](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/simple_message/html/namespaceindustrial_1_1simple__message_1_1CommTypes.html#a936c87afac003ea1d4beff7623454ce5) and the [ReplyTypes](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/simple_message/html/namespaceindustrial_1_1simple__message_1_1ReplyTypes.html#a2a1d9214ba5b19bc317758ca77f6f696) used in the header.

Finally, defined values for the `msg_type` field are documented in [REP-I0004](https://github.com/ros-industrial/rep/blob/master/rep-I0004.rst).

---

Edit: you might also be interested in the `simple_message` Wireshark [dissector](https://github.com/ros-industrial/packet-simplemessage).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gengoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/22122/gengoz/) on 2015-05-18**:
Thank you for your awnser! Do I understand correctly that the COMM_TYPE not so much indicates what is expected as an awnser, but more so what is being send? For 1: info is being send over a 'topic', for 2: a request is given and somthing is expected back, for 3: a reply to something is being given?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-18**:
Well *what is being sent* sort-of directly determines *what is expected* and vice-versa. If you send a msg that is a topic, you won't get anything back. If it is a svc req, you'll get a reply. If you send a 'topic msg' with `comm_type==svc req` you'll get a reply back, as you set it to a svc req.

**Comment by [Gengoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/22122/gengoz/) on 2015-05-18**:
I understand. Thank you. I'll mark this as best awnser.